# How do I "End process tree" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I want to delete a link of processes in Windows 10. In Windows 7 all you had to do was right click a process and hit "End process tree". How do you do that in Windows 10?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491009.aspx /t. You could also "install" Process Explorer as a replacement for Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Open **Task Manager** → *If* available click **More Details**

Two options:

- Right click to Context Menu of the process in which you want to end → Choose **Go to details** → Right click to Context Menu of the highlighted process → Choose **End Process Tree**
- Click the **Details** tab → Find your process by its Name → Right click to Context Menu → Choose **End Process Tree**